# Accelerator keys for `TActionToolBar` not working

Tags: delphi

I cannot get the accelerator keys for a `TActionToolBar` to work.

This is what I am doing (reproducable in D2006, XE4):

1. Select New -> VCL Forms Application
2. Add `ActionManager1` to the form
3. Add a new action `Action1` in `ActionManager1`, set caption of action to `&Test`
4. Add `ActionToolBar1` to the form
5. Add an item to `ActionManager.ActionBars` and set `ActionManager.ActionBars[0].ActionBar` to `ActionToolBar1`
6. Add an item to `ActionManager.ActionBars[0].Items` and set `Action` to `Action1`
7. Set the `Action1.OnExecute` event to show a message
8. Start program --> toolbar is displayed just fine and works via mouse
9. Press ALT+T --> nothing happens, but a Ding sound

What step am I missing?

Comment: As far as I know `Accelerator keys` only work on menues and not on toolbars. If you want to perform some actions that are not available though menues then you should use `Keboard shortcuts` instead. You can read more on this matter on: [Specifying Accelerator Keys and Keyboard Shortcuts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Specifying_Accelerator_Keys_and_Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Comment: Accelerator keys are for menus, as @SilverWarrior says. You're looking for the `TAction.ShortCut` property instead. If you add a menu to your form, and assign your action to it's `Action` property, the accelerator key will work.

Comment: I have never used the `TActionManager` or the `TActionToolbar` (only the ordinary `TActionList` component and regular toolbars and menus), but I would like to emphasise that keyboard accelerators very much do work on non-menu controls. For instance, on buttons (`&New category...`), check boxes (`&Update settings`), radio buttons (`&Large`), labels next to edit boxes via the `FocusControl` property (`&Name:`), etc. Accelerators also work on regular `TToolBar` controls with `TToolButton` buttons. In fact, keyboard accelerators are what makes the Windows UI usable with keyboard (for decades).

Comment: @SilverWarior As far as I know accelerator keys work for menu items, buttons, checkboxes and for toolbars (at least for TToolBar). I regulary use them. But now I want to switch from TToolBar to TActionToolBar for one project but I need to get the accelerator keys to work. Any idea?

Comment: I have no idea why this Q received a close vote for being unreproducible or being caused by a typing error. I was able to reproduce it immediately (without even reading the full list of steps in the Q).

Comment: @yonojoy Do you also use menues in those projects?

Comment: @SilverWarior No, I do not use menues in these forms (only in the main form). The relevant forms are modal subforms to a main form, which only offer a handful of actions, that are all displayed in a toolbar. We drive two different UIs with one codebase. One UI with `TToolBar` is working fine, the other one with `TActionToolBar` is missing the accelerator functionality - and nobody noticed until now :(  But now it is too late to switch the controls - I have to find a solution - maybe a workaround - for `TActionToolBar`.

Comment: @Ken Yes, using shortcuts is a possible workaround. But it is not exactly the same functionality as accelerator keys. For instance it will lead to some localization problems. Therefore I will keep searching for a solution and keep the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997674/243614) points out, action toolbars do not support this functionality.

My personal opinion is that, this has been overlooked. Toolbar buttons often showing images instead of text might be one reason to do so (at least it was for me). However, evidently, toolbar buttons have the functionality when they show their captions, so could the action toolbar buttons.

@Silver points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992263/accelerator-keys-for-tactiontoolbar-not-working#comment102408873_57997674) that action bars have the capability to find accelerated items. In fact action menus use that functionality. Same functionality could easily be integrated into `TCustomForm.IsShortCut` for action toolbars, which already iterates action lists to find possible shortcut targets.

We can override the method and do it ourselves. Below example gives priority to default handling so assigned shortcuts will suppress keyboard accelerators with the same character, but this logic could easily be reversed.

```delphi
function TForm1.IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
var
  Item: TActionClientItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := inherited IsShortCut(Message);
  if not Result and (KeyDataToShiftState(Message.KeyData) = [ssAlt]) then begin

    for i := 0 to ActionManager1.ActionBars.Count - 1 do begin
      if ActionManager1.ActionBars[i].ActionBar is TActionToolBar then begin
        Item := TActionToolBar(ActionManager1.ActionBars[i].ActionBar)
            .FindAccelItem(Message.CharCode);
        if Assigned(Item) and Item.ShowCaption and Assigned(Item.Action) 
            and Item.Action.Execute then begin
          Result := True;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is possible that an item without action exists. Therefore the last check should read `if Assigned(Item) and Item.ShowCaption and Assigned(Item.Action) and Item.Action.Execute then begin`.

Comment: I use this kind of code now in my base form class. In this way this works automatically for every TActionToolBar on all my forms. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that accelerator keys are not implemented for `TActionToolBar` - so no steps missing.

The following is not a real solution but a workaround that adds shortcuts by parsing the captions of the action (thanks to the suggestion of @KenWhite). A real solution for the question you will find in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014585/2306907). I'll keep that answer for reference anyway:

```
uses System.Actions, System.UiTypes, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ActnMan;


procedure AddShortCutsFromActionCaption(AActionMan: TActionManager);
var
    Act: TContainedAction;
    AccelKey: string;
    I: Integer;
begin
    for I := 0 to AActionMan.ActionCount - 1 do
    begin
        Act := AActionMan.Actions[I];
        if Act.ShortCut = 0 then
        begin
            AccelKey := GetHotKey(Act.Caption);
            if AccelKey <> '' then
              Act.ShortCut := TextToShortCut('Alt+' + AccelKey);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

`AddShortCutsFromActionCaption` must be run once for `ActionManager1` after the localization is run. That way the different accelerator keys for different languages remain functional.

If a shortcut already exists or if the caption of the action is modified, this workaround will not work - but for my purposes this is okay.

Comment: Please don't forget to answer the question, because this is answer space: (hint: "you are not missing any steps, that is not supposed to work at all. What should work is shortcuts").

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You are right regarding answering the question --> Edited. But I think it should work as this functionality is working in `TToolBar` too. I think they only forgot to implement.

Comment: No. It's not supposed to work, no forgetting. Toolbar buttons often even don't show their text.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I see no real difference between `TToolBar` and `TActionToolBar` (except the better integration with `TActionManager`). If one supports accelerator keys the other one should too IMHO.

Comment: `TToolBAr` by default doesn't support `Accelerator keys` on its own. You see if you create a new TToolButton by using right click on TToolBar at design time and assign your action to it using the accelerator key for that action won't do anything. But if instead you put button to your toolbar from component palate and assign action to that button then the accelerator key will work because standard buttons also have support for accelerator keys as menues do. ...

Comment: ... But unfortunately you can't put button on TActionToolbar this way as TActionToolbar uses its own way of rendering these buttons and doesn't contain them as child components the way TToolBar does.

Comment: @SilverWarior That's wrong: Take the example from the question. Add a `TToolbar`. Right click the toolbar to add a button. Set `Action` property of the ToolButton to `Action1`. Set `ShowCaptions` of the toolbar to True (otherwise no captions / no accelerators). Start the program and press `ALT+T`.

Comment: @yonojoy I stand corrected. Any way after some more in-depth searching in `TActionToolBar` source I found out that `TCustomActionBar` class contains a method named `FindAccelItem` which should search through all buttons and to see if one of them has certain accelerator key assigned but during my testing this method never even fires. I couldn't also find a code that would even call this method. So it seems as the method exists but is never used. In `TToolBar` class similar method is executed from `WMSysCommand` and `CMDialogChar` message handlers that `TActionToolBar` doesn't even have.

Comment: @Silver - Action menus use FindAccelItem. It can be used here too. Override IsShortCut of the form for instance. Then if inherited handling returns false, you can call FindAccelItem and execute the action of a possible item it returns.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz + SilverWarior: That seems to work - would you like to provide this as an answer? It is a better solution than [my workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997674/2306907). Thanks for your help.